# How to check the correct member account type with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, member

I need to make a registration page for members on my website/webapplication, but the problem is that there is 3 different account types: employees, freelancers and jobseekers. I have some ideas of where to start but i don't know if it will work.. i just want some feedback about whether i am on the right path with my ideas.

Registration form

Should i make 3 different registration forms for each account type? or can i use 1 webpage divided into 3 different sections for each account type?

Database/Tables MySQL

Should i make a different table in my database for each different account type? or can i just add an extra column to the current existing users table that indicates the "account type"?

PHP script to check the account type and then show the correct profile page

How can i redirect each account type to the right profile page when the user is logging in?

Comment: i dont thin you are asking this question on correct website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's preferer to use one login page and redirect everyone to his role page.

On DB use one table and add a new column named ROLE, and change it with the role of everyone and set "USER" like a default role

Comment: Thanks Sayou! there is different ways to solve this problem but i like your solution because i just have to add 1 column to the database users table to distinguish between the different account types.

Comment: @JhonattanRapprecht I'm glad to like my solution, I think most websites use these methods

Answer (score 1):

You have three account type. You should make a single registration page and make two tabs. Each tabs have it's forms, One form for job seeker and another one is for freelancer. User will select the tabs and choose one of them. You should make another page(url) for employee separate because every user visited on your site, an not be employee. 
In database you should manage job seeker and freelancer in one table and add a field type. For employee make another table because emlployee have a lot of field which will not be in jobseeker and employee. you have less employee and more users(jobseeker and freelancer) so keep it separate. 
Same secenario will follow in login. Single login for users(job seekers and freelancer) and separate login for employee. When user is login go and check in db  then you will get it's type and redirect them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Kuldeep for the insight!